# What is the material on top of the chips in this logic board, and should I leave them?

Tags: heatsink, identification

This is a very beginner-ish question.  I didn't know where else to ask, or even what terms to search for, so I hope this is the right place.

I'm replacing the logic board on a monitor.

The replacement board came with this gray material covering all the delicate parts (see image; one has the position skewed on purpose)[image: logic board].

What is it?  Was it for protection in packaging, or is it a heat conducting material?

Should I leave them all, or remove a few?

It's clear that a couple were left on the original board, but not as many as came attached to the replacement.

Thanks!

Comment: Were they there on the original board (which you pulled from the display)? If not, then just install the new one the way the old one came out! =)

Answer (score 4):

They're to protect the IC package against mechanical impact. Total height of such an IC may be less than 1 mm, so you can imagine the top of the package is only a couple of tenths of a mm thick. A sharp object will go right through it and destroy the die.

Looks overkill to me. The photo shows bubble foil too, and there's usually a few cm between board and the carton box. If during handling a sharp object can penetrate 3 cm deep into the carton, and still have enough energy to break the IC's package your handling process really needs a critical review.

Also the rest of the board isn't protected. That same sharp object may scratch the PCB, cutting traces, or chip off a small SMT capacitor.

You can throw them away.

Answer (score 2):

I am not positive but I think that's just protection and not a thermally conductive foam material like [this](http://www.bergquistcompany.com/thermal_materials/gap-pad.htm). I would not expect a logic board to need thermally conductive foam.

Comment: I'm pretty sure thermally conductive *foam* is something of an oxymoron. Anything with a cellular structure like foam, and gas filling the cells is going to be a pretty effective insulator. I would guess the pads are somewhat granular. It may be ferrite squares. I'd bet it's just packaging, though.

Comment: @FakeName: if they would be ferrite, what would be their purpose?

Comment: @FakeName I guess foam was not the best word to use... instead padding or filler as that particular manufacturer refers to it.

Comment: OK :) a thermally conductive sponge material.

Answer (score 1):

In contrast, /I/ think that it is thermal foam ('gap pad'), and that the board is designed to be mounted flush against a metal surface.

But I can only imagine the mounting system: you haven't given us a picture.

Comment: It's not a *foam* if it's thermally conductive.  It could be a thermal *pad*, because there is something that looks like an EMC gasket on the board.

Comment: ... However, while sponges are made of sponge rubber, most thermal pads are made of two phases: a foam and a filler.